# Why is this chunk of code creating a seg fault?

Tags: pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm wondering what's going on in the background that creates a seg fault.

```
char *ptr;
fgets(ptr, 200, stdin);
fprintf(stderr, "Ptr = %s\n", ptr);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never allocated space for `fgets` to write into. So the variable `ptr` is uninitialized, and dereferencing it results in undefined behavior. The segfault occurred because the value happened to point to unavailable memory.

```
char *ptr = malloc(200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ptr is an uninitialised (could be anything) variable. So fgets dumps data at an unknown location. Boom.